# How to handle input of one type and output of another

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns

I have an extremeley small and simple class but it is giving me some problems in how best to deal with it.

It has a constructor and a single get method.

The purpose is to store an array of values and return them when asked via the get method.

Additionally, the array of values might be passed as a comma separate string to the constructor.  And this is where i cant decide how to handle things.

1. Should the constructor split the string and trim element before storing the property
2. Should the constructor simply store the property and each time the getter is called, the property should be split
3. Should the getter check the property and if its a string, split it and then store the value for future calls to getter not have to
   ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it in the constructor. That is only going to be called once. If you do it in the getter you'll have to do the split many times.

Comment: There's even more compelling reasons than just having to call split more times

Answer (score 2):

On the assumption that you're going to call `get` at least once, the first option would be preferable.

The second option has the disadvantage that you may need to split many times, which can take quite a performance toll if you're calling `get` a lot.

The third option has the disadvantage that you'll likely need to have either 2 variables (a string and an array), only one of which will be used at a time, or have the type be an `Object`, which would then be either a string or an array. Neither of these options are particularly good design.

If you're often *not* calling `get` at least once, or if you need access to the original string, the third option might make sense (at least from a performance point of view, the first option is still a better design), but I'd be fairly concerned about your design if this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Should the constructor split the string and trim element before storing the property
> 2. Should the constructor simply store the property and each time the getter is called, the property should be split
> 3. Should the getter check the property and if its a string, split it and then store the value for future calls to getter not have to ...

I'll address each of these individually.

1. With this approach, you do all of your initialization when the class is being created. This is generally good practice, and it allows your class definition (what fields there are) to really match what the class should be.
2. With this approach, your constructor is simple, but now your getter becomes complicated and your class definition is now not as clear. You have to explain in a comment somewhere that `property.split(",")[4]` is something specific
3. This is way more complicated logic for something like this than needed. Please don't do this

In conclusion, #1 seems like the best solution to me.

Answer (score 1):

In Effective Java by Joshua Bloch one can read that you should be as lazy as possible with operations and only do things when they are really needed, such as initializing variables etc.

So following that suggestion I would do something like this:

```
public class Example  {
    private String string;
    private String[] array;

    public Example(String string){
        this.string = string;
    }

    public Example(String[] array){
        this.array = array;
    }

    public String[] getValues(){
        if(this.array == null){
            //Split the string, trim the values
            //create a new array and assign it to the array-variable
            this.string = null; //no need to keep it any longer
        } 
        return this.array;
    }
}
```

Comment: This was the 3rd item on my list, but it seems to be going against the grain of all other answers so far

Comment: You shouldn't be constructing something if you're not going to be using it, thus splitting the string in the constructor essentially constitutes the same amount of work as this, except that in the constructor is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is you who should decide if you ever need an original string. If you don't it is logical choice to have job done in the constructor.

Comment: If this was the case, I would still prefer splitting the string in the constructor, but also store the original string.